# i want to get response from nodejs to angular 6

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, angular6

i want to send response message if insert query is successful if not then nodejs should send unsuccessful message to angular 6 and display that on browser
    //nodejs file

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    let uname = req.body.username;
    let mail = req.body.email;


    con.query('SELECT username FROM customers WHERE username = ?', uname,(err,result)=>{

        if(err) throw err;
        con.query('SELECT email FROM customers WHERE email = ?', mail,(err, results) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(result.length !=0 || results.length != 0){
                console.log('email and username already exists');
                res.send({msg:"already registered with the email and username"});
            }
            else{
                con.query('INSERT INTO customers SET ?', req.body, (err, results) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    res.status(200).json(results);
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
//service.ts file
addCustomer (customer: Customer): Observable<Customer> {

    return this.http.post<Customer>(this.customersUrl, customer, httpOptions);
}

//create component file
addCustomer() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.save();
}
private save(): void {
    this.customerService.addCustomer(this.customer)
        .subscribe(result=>console.log('success'));
}
```

Comment: use promise with then chain and you can send response on success and failure.
**success .then and catch functions**

Comment: can you please explain

Answer (score 0):

write api functions with then chain. You can get the error in catch. Return whatever you needed in success function and error function.
Example:

```
 getQueryResults()
       .then(processResultData)
       .then((result)=>{
         return result;
       })
       .catch((error)=>{
         return error;
       });
```